# How to extend bash shell?

Tags: bash, command-line, queue

would like to add new functionality to the bash shell. I need to have a queue for executions.

What is the easy way to add new functionality to the bash shell keeping all native functions?
I would like to process the command line, then let the bash to execute them. For users it should be transparent.

Thanks Arman

**EDIT**

I just discovered prll.sourceforge.net it does exactly what I need.

Comment: what do you mean "queue for executions"?  Are you talking about running multiple commands at the same time?  If so bash already does that, just separate the commands with a semicolon.

Comment: Yes, but I mean: asumming a & b & c & d, and you have only 2 CPUs, I would like to run only 2 processes at the same time.

Comment: Though not a general solution, if you want to run the same command in parallel on a list of arguments, then `xargs` and the `-P` flag can do this, as can [`parallel`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(software\)), which also supports the switch `-j+0`, automatically detecting the number of CPUs.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks Nick. In that sence I can also use the Makefile with -j option.

Comment: So... the question in the title is how to extend the shell, but in reality there's a very specific use case, such that an answer speaking to the general question of extension mechanisms without addressing that use case wouldn't be applicable. Moreover, the use case is described in a way far to general to be readily understandable in the question, and only clarified in the comments. -1 on this question.

Answer (score 2):

Its easier than it seems:

```
#!/bin/sh
yourfunctiona(){ ...; }
...
yourfunctionz(){ ...; }
. /path/to/file/with/more/functions

while read COMMANDS; do
  eval "$COMMANDS"
done
```

you can use read -p if you need a prompt or -t if you want it to timeout ... or if you wanted you could even use your favorite dialog program in place of read and pipe the output to a tailbox

```
touch /tmp/mycmdline
Xdialog --tailbox /tmp/mycmdline 0 0 &
COMMANDS="echo "
while ([ "$COMMANDS" != "" ]); do
  COMMANDS=`Xdialog --stdout --inputbox "Text here" 0 0`
  eval "$COMMANDS"
done >>/tmp/mycmdline &
```

To execute commands in threads you can use the following in place of eval $COMMANDS

```
#this will need to be before the loope
NUMCORES=$(awk '/cpu cores/{sum += $4}END{print sum}' /proc/cpuinfo)

for i in {1..$NUMCORES};do
  if [ $i -eq $NUMCORES ] && #see comments below
  if [ -d /proc/$threadarray[$i] ]; then #this core already has a thread
#note: each process gets a directory named /proc/<its_pid> - hacky, but works
    continue
  else #this core is free
    $COMMAND &
    threadarray[$i]=$!
    break
fi
done
```

Then there is the case where you fill up all threads.
You can either put the whole thing in a while loop and add continues and breaks,
or you can pick a core to wait for (probably the last) and wait for it

to wait for a single thread to complete use:

```
wait $threadarray[$i]
```

to wait for all threads to complete use:

```
 wait
#I ended up using this to keep my load from getting to high for too long
```

another note: you may find that some commands don't like to be threaded, if so you can put the whole thing in a case statement

I'll try to do some cleanup on this soon to put all of the little blocks together (sorry, I'm cobbling this together from random notes that I used to implement this exact thing, but can't seem to find)

Comment: sorry, that would be a few extra lines depending on how many threads you want to support (It sounded like you already had a function for that) ... would you prefer simpler code with bashisms or longer but more portable shell that will run with busybox ash/hush?

Comment: for example I can parallelize the calls with make -j ntreads, if I write correct Makefile, but with bash its little bit non trivial for me.